# hijri to gregorian date, why 30/02/1436 doesn't exist in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have being confused as SQL cannot convert (Saudi Arabian dates) Hijra to Gregorian calendar as cannot convert the 30/02/1436.

2nd month is called Safar. Does Safar has 30 or 29 days?

Tank you for your time, 
Regards,

Comment: If Safar = February in Gregorian, then the question is does it have 28 or 29 days? Divide the year by 4 and if you don't get a remainder, then it's considered a leap year that will have 29 days, otherwise it only has 28 days in February.

Comment: Hijri Calendar follows lunar cycles, so any month can be either `29` or `30`.

Comment: welcome to SO, please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Which command did you send, which error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

**PS: Safar in year 1436 only had 29 days**

Does this work for you?

[CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) date format 130 and 131 are for Hijri datetimes

```
DECLARE @DateTimeNow DATETIME = GETUTCDATE() ;
-- Get Gregorian UTC datetime
SELECT @DateTimeNow --2017-11-15 17:10:52.110

-- Get Hijri datetime
SELECT CONVERT(nchar, @DateTimeNow, 131) --26/02/1439  5:10:52:110PM     

--Convert back again
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nchar, @DateTimeNow, 131), 131) --2017-11-15 17:10:52.110
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately not. That function is developed to work for Hijra Kuwait calendar but not for Hijra Saudi Arabia Calendar.

They have some differences. 

Regards,

Comment: If the issue is that the Kuwaiti Hijri calendar is different to the one in SQL Server (Saudi version) then you will have to create your own Kuwaiti version Hijri calender table and query against that